# Detected SURF Feature location

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, surf

I am using SURF on image size of 60*83 with varying scale levels and `MetricThreshold` to generate more blobs. But location of `points2` vector showing coordinates which is beyond the dimension of input image size. I really wonder why it is. I need to obtain exact coordinate of detected key-points.

```
I2 = rgb2gray(Temp);                          %I2= 60*83 uint8
points2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2,'NumScaleLevels',6,'MetricThreshold',600);
```

I am trying to get location of the detected points in command window and it is showing following coordinates ([see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CafOl.jpg) the highlighted x-axis coordinate exceeding dimension).
But if I use following code then only all coordinates are inside the image dimension.

```
points2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2);
```

I need to do this using varying scale levels and MetricThreshold. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a simple x,y/row,column confusion?

Comment: no sir..I checked multiple times..with variation of No of Scales, locations are coming beyond Image dimension

Answer (score 1):

matlab stores matrix as nOfRows x nOfCols

detectSURFFeatures returns positions as [x,y]

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/surfpoints-class.html

so results are in range.

Answer (score 0):

What does `size(I2)` return? From what you wrote, I would expect it to return `[60, 83]`, where 60 is the height of the image (number of rows), and 83 is the width (number of columns). If so, then your results make perfect sense, because the `SURFPoints` locations are [x,y].

You can also see if your points make sense by visualizing them:

```
imshow(I2)
hold on
plot(points2)
```